# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x1b5905868) to 'NSDecimalNumber' (0x1b5912c70)

Tags: json, swift

```
//parse the recieved Data to JSON
//check if Data is valid JSON
    if(recvdata != nil) {
        if let parsedJson : AnyObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: recvdata!, options: []) as AnyObject?{
            //Data is valid JSON
            print("Json parsed")
            if let _ = parsedJson as? NSDictionary {
                //JSON is valid NSDictionary
                if((parsedJson.value(forKey: "res")! as! NSObject) as! Decimal == 1) {
                    print("Synchronization success")
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    print("Synchronization failed")
                    return false
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Error in converting JSON to NSDictionary")
                return false
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error in parsing JSON-Answer")
            return false
        }
    }
    else {
        print("recvdata == nil! No response to synchronous request!")
        return false
    }
```

After receiving the data i want to parse the data to JSON-format. But in the following line the error

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x1b5905868) to
>   'NSDecimalNumber' (0x1b5912c70)."

occurs.

```
if((parsedJson.value(forKey: "res")! as! NSObject) as! Decimal == 1) {
```

In Xcode 2 it worked:

```
if((parsedJson.valueForKey("res")! as! NSObject == 1) {
```

please help me to fix this error!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to a `Bool` instead:

```
if parsedJson["res"]! as! NSNumber as Bool {
```

or even better, directly and without forced unwrapping:

```
if parsedJson["res"] as? Bool ?? false {
```

`Decimal` is rather a specific decimal type and it does not make sense to cast to it just to get the boolean value.

However, using a dedicated type-safe casting library, e.g. SwiftyJSON would be a better solution.

Comment: If I write Bool instead of Decimal the Error " 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSObject' " appears.

Comment: Why two casts and three uses of `!`. Shudder.

Comment: because when i write "as NSObject", Xcode says i have to replace it by "as! NSObject) as! Decimal"

Comment: @rmaddy You are right, I have added a better and simpler solution

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many issues with the code you posted. You have far too many forced unwraps of optionals that will lead to crashes. You don't properly deal with the `try` when parsing the data. You use `NSDictionary` instead of a Swift dictionary. And you don't properly get the value for the `"res"` key which is the cause of the immediate error.

I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
if let data = recvdata {
    do {
        if let parsedJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: recvdata, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
            if let res = parsedJson["res"] as? Bool {
                return res
            } else {
                // No res value (or it's not a Bool)
            }
        } else {
            // Not a dictionary
        }
    } catch {
        // Can't parse data
    }
} else {
    // no data
}

return false
```

Note the use of safely unwrapping optionals. Note the use of `do/catch` to handled the use of `try`. Note the use of a Swift dictionary.

Comment: And then I would use `guard` statement(s) :) Also note you don't have to include the `options:` parameter if you're not passing any.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

- In Swift 3 JSON `AnyObject` is replaced with `Any`.
- Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift at all, you are fighting the strong type system.
- Don't use `valueForKey:` unless you really need KVC (and can explain why).

---

```
if let parsedJson = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: recvdata!) as? [String:Any] {
    if let resValue = parsedJson["res"] as? Bool, resValue == true {
        print("Synchronization success")
        return true
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me :)